# Quick script to compare checksums

Tags: shell-script

I have a bunch of files and need to verify their checksums. I have a text file that looks like:

checksum `<tab>` filename `<new line>`

Figured I'd use this as an exercise to improve my shell scripting. This is what I came up with and it did the trick, I'm just curious if there's a better way. I realize that it's not very flexible (such as assuming the file's format and the algorithm is 256). But I tried to avoid `cat` and `echo`...  :)

Thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh

workingDir="/path/to/directory/"
textFile="checksums.txt"
filePath="$workingDir$textFile"

while read a b; do
    shasumOutput=$(/usr/bin/shasum -a 256 "$workingDir$b" | /usr/bin/awk '{ print $1 }')
    if [ "$a" = "$shasumOutput" ]; then
        /usr/bin/printf "$b checksum matches: "$a", "$shasumOutput"\n"
    else
        /usr/bin/printf "$b checksum doesn't match: "$a", "$shasumOutput"\n"
    fi
done < "$filePath"
```

Comment: You know that you are reproducing the behavior of `shasum -c <file>`, right?

Comment: Yeah... like I said, it was an excuse to work on a script.  :)  Not sure how the text file needs to be formatted to use the -c flag.

Answer (score 2):

As [Gohu points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373545/quick-script-to-compare-checksums#comment664413_373545) in comments, you are reproducing the checking that `shasum` already does with its `-c` flag.

The input to `shasum -c` should be what's produced by `shasum`.

Ignoring that...

Your script looks ok, but I can comment on some things in it.

The `printf` lines are better written as `printf 'format string' "$var1" "$var2" "etc."`, e.g. instead of

```
/usr/bin/printf "$b checksum matches: "$a", "$shasumOutput"\n"
```

use

```
printf '%s checksum matches: %s, %s\n' "$b" "$a" $shasumOutput"
```

The whole point of using `printf` is that you have a static format string followed by several bits of variable data that goes into the format string's template.

Also, to avoid `$( shasum ... )` and to reduce the number of calls to external utilities, this is what I would have done:

```
#!/bin/sh

checkdir='/some/path'
checkfile="$checkdir/checksums.txt"

while read -r checksum filename; do
    if [ ! -f "$checkdir/$filename" ]; then
        printf 'Not found: %s\n' "$filename"
        continue
    fi

    gsha256sum "$checkdir/$filename" |  {
        read -r realsum name
        if [ "$realsum" != "$checksum" ]; then
            printf 'Mismatch for "%s":\n\t%s != %s\n' \
                "$filename" "$checksum" "$realsum"
        else
            printf '%s OK\n' "$filename"
        fi
    }
done <"$checkfile" >&2
```

This reduces the number of external utility calls (in most shells) to one (the SHA256 utility).

The GNU coreutils utility to produce SHA256 checksums on my OpenBSD system is called `gsha256sum`. I'm assuming that its output is identical to `shasum -a 256` on your system.

Some notes:

- I generally don't put `/` at the end of directory names. Instead I insert the delimiter when using the variable. This way I can see directly that `$checkdir/checksum.txt` is a path to a file, whereas `${checkdir}checksum.txt` (or similar) is more ambiguous.
- I check whether the file actually exists before trying to verify its checksum.
- Instead of parsing the output of the SHA256 program using `awk`, I read it in the same way as I read the checksum and filename from the checksum file. I do this in a `{ ...; }` context.
- I'm treating *all* output from the loop as "diagnostic messages" and redirect it all to standard error with `>&2` after `done`.
- I tend not to use absolute paths to utilities in scripts unless there's a real reason to do so. `printf`, for example, is almost always a shell built-in utility and there's seldom a reason to use `/usr/bin/printf` explicitly.

You could most likely get away with a single call (or very few calls) to the SHA256 utility by invoking it with all filenames from the input file and then comparing the checksums from that call, but the code may be slightly convoluted and the effort would not be worth it if this is a one-off thing and if the input file is not huge.